# Javamelody with Tomcat and MySql

Tags: mysql, tomcat

I have setup a web application in Tomcat with Javamelody and MySql. I am able to see the JDBC connection details under system info so I know that Javamelody is able to connect to the database. I have executed select/update statements from my application but nothing is ever shown on the monitoring page under statistics sql. I have executed "show full processlist" using the same user as my database connection and it works fine. I can't work out what I am doing wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Don't mess monitoring tool into problem.
You can check if connection works without it. 
(E.g. create table and insert some data and then check if table exists).